# infinity looping while training dataset validation_data dan training_data in deep learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I try to input `validation_data` parameter in `model.fit` like this:

```
val_generator = data_generator(validation, mapping, features, tokenizer, max_length, vocab_size, batch_size)

train_generator = data_generator(train, mapping, features, tokenizer, max_length, vocab_size, batch_size)

history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    epochs=40,
                    steps_per_epoch=steps,
                    callbacks = callback,
                    validation_data = val_generator,
                    verbose=1 )
```

and i get a problem is infinity looping. i wanna show val_loss dan val_accuracy from this code as output.

i add validation_data = val_generator in code. The result is infinity looping.
I want to show val_loss dan val_accuracy from my code.
can u guys help me fix it? please.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another parameter to your model.fit() call, which is **validation_steps** (validation_steps: Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset. Total number of steps (batches of samples) to draw before stopping when performing validation at the end of every epoch)
https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/

Since you are using the same version of data_generator for both training and validation and you only specified the steps per epoch for training, then you need to do the same for validation so the fit method can know in each epoch how many batches to bring.